# how to update_attributes values in Rails4

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am new to ROR and working currently on Rails4. I have problem in accessing attr_accessible and update_attributes. I want to update a boolean value to true if the check box is checked.
Here goes my code

## controller.rb

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController

before_action :signed_in_user, only: [:edit, :new, :show, :destroy, :index]

def new
    @task =current_user.tasks.new
end

def create
    @task= current_user.tasks.new(params[:task].permit(:name, :taskname ))

    if @task.save
      redirect_to @task
     else
     render 'new'
    end
end

def show
    user = Task.find(params[:id]).user.id
    if user == current_user.id
       @task =current_user.tasks.find(params[:id])
    else
     flash[:notice] = "Access Denied "
      redirect_to tasks_path
    end
   end

  def index
 
@task=current_user.tasks.all
  end

def edit
 user = Task.find(params[:id]).user.id
 if user == current_user.id
  @task =current_user.tasks.find(params[:id])
 else
  flash[:notice] = "Access Denied "
   redirect_to tasks_path
 end
end
def update
  @task = current_user.tasks.find(params[:id])

   if @task.update(params[:task].permit(:name,:taskname))
  redirect_to @task
  else
  render 'edit'
  end
end

def destroy
 @task = current_user.tasks.find(params[:id])
 @task.destroy

 redirect_to tasks_path
end

def done
 @task = current_user.tasks.find(params[:id])
 if @task.done
  @task.update_attributes(completed: false)
 else 
  @task.update_attributes(completed: true)
 end    
end

private

def signed_in_user
  redirect_to new_user_registration_path, notice: "Please sign in." unless signed_in?
 end
end
```

I am getting an error as NoMethodError in Tasks#index

My checkbox code in index is as follows:

## index.html.erb

```
  <h1>Listing tasks</h1>
   <div id="new">
    <%= link_to 'Add new task', new_task_path, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
   </div><p>
  <table class="PersonList">
    <tr>
       <th>TaskName</th>
        <th>PersonName</th>
 
    </tr>

     <% @task.each do |task| %>
     <tr>
       <td class="checklist_check" ><%= check_box_tag "complete_task", task.id, task.done,  :class => 'complete_task'   %> <%= task.taskname%></td>
        <td> <%= task.name %> </td>
  
   <td><%= link_to 'Show', task_path(task) %></td>
   <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_task_path(task) %></td>
   <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', task_path(task), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
```

and my js file is:

## tasks.js

```
$(function(){
$(".complete_task").live("change", function(task_id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/tasks/done",
        data: "id="+task_id, 
        success: function() { alert('completed') }
    });
  });
});
```

What is the reason for getting NoMethod Error inspite of mentioning the method done in controller.

I also gave my routes properly.

My main concern is how to use strong parameters in Rails4 and update_attributes instantly for boolean to change form true to false and vice versa.

Thank you!!

Comment: could you add the error text as well as the output of rake routes?

Comment: NoMethodError in Tasks#index                                undefined method `done' for #<Task:0xa9b38e0>
Extracted source (around line #15):
      <% @task.each do |task| %>
        <tr>
          <td class="checklist_check" ><%= check_box_tag "complete_task", task.id, task.done,  :class => 'complete_task'   %> <%= task.taskname%></td>
          <td> <%= task.name %> </td>                           The error is at the check_box_tag

Answer (score 0):

You have to use it like this

```
@task.update_attribute :completed, false
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like

```
  def done
    @task = current_user.tasks.find(params[:id])
    @task.update_attributes(completed: true)
  end
```

Or

```
 def done
    @task = current_user.tasks.find(params[:id])
    @task.update_attribute(:completed, true)

 end
```

your checkbox should be like

```
 <% if task.completed == true %> 
 <%= check_box_tag "complete_task", task.id, true, :class => 'complete_task'   %>
 <% else %>
 <%= check_box_tag "complete_task", task.id, true, :class => 'not_complete_task'   %>
 <% end %> 




$(function(){
 $(".complete_task").live("change", function(task_id) {
   $.ajax({
    url: "/tasks/done",
    data: "id="+task_id, 
    success: function() {$(this).css({}); } #style for strike out
    });
  });
 });
```

Comment: I have changed my code as per your suggession but i am getting NoMethodError in Tasks#index. First of all my code is not showing any index page which contains checkbox.

Comment: ooh then it is not the problem for my code.....do you have any `index` method in tasks controller hope not...create a index method in tasks controller `def index #something whatever you want end`

Comment: I have index method.I am running a CRUD app.But now i am getting an error like           NoMethodError in Tasks#index undefined method `done' for #<Task:0xa9b38e0> Extracted source (around line #15): <% @task.each do |task| %> <tr> <td class="checklist_check" ><%= check_box_tag "complete_task", task.id, task.done, :class => 'complete_task' %> <%= task.taskname%></td> <td> <%= task.name %> </td> The error is at the check_box_tag

Comment: can you please update your post with your controller code and model code?as it is comming for `<%= check_box_tag "complete_task", task.id, task.done, :class => 'complete_task' %>` what is done method?

Comment: I have edited my post just have a look and mention what mistake i have done.

Comment: `done` method should be in model not in controller `task.done` and what you want to do using `done` ? here `task` is the instance of your model class and you call a controller method

Comment: when I click on the check box I want the text beside it to be striked off by ' css: text-decoration line-through '. I am able to do it with JQuery but if I refresh the page I cant find the line on text. so I thought of using ajax. As I am new to this I am not able to get the task with AJAX.

Comment: please read it http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

Comment: in your ajax success you have to `success: function() { $(".complete_task").css({}); }`

Comment: look there is a lot of bug on your code please follow my post